# call a struct attribute of a struct via pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers

```
struct Test1 {
   struct Test2 {
      DWORD VA1 = 0;
      DWORD VA2 = 0;
      Test2(DWORD hp):VA1(hp) { }
   } *Ppy[5];

   Test1() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      *(Ppy + i) = new Test2((DWORD)i+2);
   }

   ~Test1() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         delete *(Ppy + i);
   }
};

void main() {
   Test1*Als = new Test1;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      Als->Ppy[i]->VA2;
      // doesn't work->  cout << Als->*(Ppy + i)->VA2 << endl;

   delete Als;
}
```

Hello

1. How to convert this whole line(if possible) or at least `Ppy[i]` to
   Pointer style/arithmetic : `Als->Ppy[i]->VA2`

   Something like this but it doesn't work : `Als->*(Ppy + i)->VA2`
2. Is there a way to make this even more complex (not `asm` deep)?

Comment: You seem to know that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i` the expressions `p[i]` and `*(p + i)` are equal. Why would you rather use the (IMO) harder to read pointer arithmetic? It's also more characters to write if you're lazy.

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this.  (Also, please [edit] your code to format it properly.)

Comment: `Ppy[i]` **is** pointer arithmetic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    Als->Ppy[i]->VA2;
```

You can write:

```
   (*(Als->Ppy + i))->VA2;
```

- The pointer to the array is `Als->Ppy`
- The pointer to an element of the array is `Als->Ppy + i`
- The value of an element of the array is `*(Als->Ppy + i)`

The value of an element of the array is itself a pointer, and you need to wrap the above expression in parens before using it to point to an element of the structure.

Comment: doesn't work T_T left of'->VA2' must point to class/struct/union/generic type | expression must have pointer-to-class type

Comment: Yup.  Should be `(*(Als->Ppy + i))->VA2;` I think, but  cpp.sh doesn't like that either.  Breaking it down.

Comment: @VTT: You are correct that `*(Als->Ppy + i)` is a reference to array item - *but that array item is a pointer*.  (It is an array of pointers.)  See http://cpp.sh/9npzl